# Shell script in Kubernetes worker pod

Tags: shell, kubernetes

I have a requirement to run a shell script from worker pod. For that I have created the configMap and loaded as volume. When I applied the configuration, I see a directory in the name of shell script is created is created. Can you help to understand why I see this behavior.

```
 volumes:
    - name: rhfeed
      configMap: 
        name: rhfeed
        defaultMode: 0777

      volumeMounts:
        - name: rhfeed
          mountPath: /local_path/rh-feed/rh-generator.sh
          subPath: rh-generator.sh
          readOnly: true
```

---

```
drwxrwsrwx 2 root 1000 4096 Jun 22 06:55 rh-generator.sh
```

Comment: you mount path should be a directory. mountPath: /local_path/rh-feed/

Comment: when I add only /local_path/rh-feed/, I dont see the script under that path.

Answer (score 0):

`rh-generator.sh` folder created because used have used `subPath`.

`subPath` creates a separate folder.

Comment: I have tried that as well and not working.

Comment: Actually the same setup is working in another environment, but the only difference is in my new setup, kubenernetes is using kustomization. So the shell script is added in a newly created ConfigMap and then loaded to worker pod using a volume.

Answer (score 0):

I have just performed a test with `ConfigMap` serving some static files for the `nginx` pod and my file was mounted correctly without overriding nor create deleting the content of the directory.

Here's the `configMap` yaml file:

```sh
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: static-files
data:
  index.html: |
    <html><head><title>File Mounted from ConfigMap</title></head>
    <body><h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Hi, This confirm that your yaml with subPath is working fine</p>
    </body></html>
```

And here the `pod` yaml file:

```sh
➜  ~ cat pod-static-files.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: website
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: static-files
      configMap:
        name: static-files
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        - name: static-files
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/index.html
          subPath: index.html
```

As you can see below I has mounted the file into the directory without any issues:

```sh
➜  ~ keti website bash 
root@website:~# ls /usr/share/nginx/
html  index.html
```

And here is the content of the `/usr/share/nginx/index.html` file:

```html
➜ root@website:~# cat /usr/share/nginx/index.html 

<html><head><title>File Mounted from ConfigMap</title></head>
<body><h1>Welcomet</h1>
<p>Hi, This confirm that your yaml with subPath is working fine</p>
</body></html>
```